# How to add conditional count based on mutiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to summarise a T-SQL output that looks a little like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| perf_no | section | row | seat  |
+---------+---------+-----+-------+
|    7128 |       6 | A   |     4 |
|    7128 |       6 | A   |     5 |
|    7128 |       6 | A   |     7 |
|    7128 |       6 | A   |     9 |
|    7128 |       6 | A   |    28 |
|    7129 |       6 | A   |    29 |
|    7129 |       6 | A   |     8 |
|    7129 |       6 | A   |     9 |
|    7129 |       8 | A   |     6 |
|    7129 |       8 | B   |     3 |
|    7129 |       8 | B   |     4 |
+---------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Comparing one row to the row(s) below, if the perf_no, section, and row values are the same, and the difference between the seat values is 1, then I want to consider them a group, and count the number of rows in that group.

To give you a real world example, these are seats in a theatre! I'm trying to summarise what seats are available.

Using the table above to illustrate:

- rows 1 & 2 show that seats 4 & 5 in section 6, row 8 for performance 7128 are available. So that's 2 seats together
- row 3 shows that 7 in sectino 6, row 8 for performance 7128 is available on its own. So that's a single seat (1)
- rows 5 & 6 have the same section and row, and the seats are consecutive, but you can see the performance is different. So that's a single seat too.

So the output for the table above would look a little like...

(I've left in the spaces just so visually you can see the groupings more easily - obviously the final version will have none)

```
+---------+---------+----------+-------+
| perf_no | section | seat_row | total |
+---------+---------+----------+-------+
|    7128 |       6 | A        |     2 |
|         |         |          |       |
|    7128 |       6 | A        |     1 |
|    7128 |       6 | A        |     1 |
|    7128 |       6 | A        |     1 |
|    7129 |       6 | A        |     1 |
|    7129 |       6 | A        |     2 |
|         |         |          |       |
|    7129 |       6 | A        |     1 |
|    7129 |       8 | B        |     2 |
+---------+---------+----------+-------+
```

I've been trying to use some conditional case statements to not much avail. Any assistance very gratefully received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can generate a grouping by subtracting a sequence (generated by `row_number()`) from the `seat`:

```
select perf_no, section, row, count(*) as num_seats,
       min(seat) as first_seat, max(seat) as last_seat
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by perf_no, section, row order by seat) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by perf_no, section, row, (seat - seqnum);
```